# MongoDB Last value or Max value using C#

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0

I am facing issues in retrieving the Latest value from the MongoDB table (Collection).

My table doesn't have a class mapped. I cannot create a class for my table due to the dynamic behaviour.

For Eg 
MyTable has 4 columns mentioned below is the table and values.

```
Id , DateTime,  Column1, Column2

1     somTime     1         1
2     somTime     2         2
3     somTime     3
```

Due to the user requirements the table is dynamic, the user can create as many columns he want and he can insert values in to these  columns separately. 
In this I want to get the latest value inserted in the Column2 which is 2.

My code looks like this.

```
var maxDateTime = (from collect in document.AsQueryable()
                   select collect["dateTime"]).Max();

var qLatestValue = Query.EQ("DateTime", maxDateTime);
value = result["Column1"];   
// this works fine since the Column1 exists

value = result["Column2"];

// this code is giving exception
```

The Column2 is not present in the document retrieved. Due to this its throwing keynotFound exception.

How to get the latest value of this Column2?
Can any one please help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. Below code fixed my issue.

```
var maxDateTime =(from a in document.AsQueryable() where c[columnName] != BsonNull.Value select c["DateTime"]).Max();

var qlatest= Query.EQ("DateTime", maxDateTime);
var result = document.FindOne(qlatest);
value = result[columnName];
```

Comment: *** Its  c  instead of a in (from a in document.AsQueryable()

Answer (score 1):

Your `result` doesn't have a filed named `Column2` in your document. The solution is getting value via

Way 1:

```
result["Column2", BsonNull.Value]
```

Way 2:

```
result.GetValue("Column2", BsonNull.Value);
```

Way 3:

```
BsonValue value;
var hasValue = doc.TryGetValue("Column2");
```

Comment: Thank you.  This helped in finding the correct solution. I have provided the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

When you are retrieving the `maxDateTime`value you are retrieving the most recent one in the collection but this document may not contain the `Column2` key

You will need to include a `Where` clause in your `maxDateTime` query any only get the `maxDateTime` for documents where the `Column2` key exists.

e.g

```
Query.Exists("Column2")
```

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working. If you are happy with the answer will you mark it as accepted please?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but actually the solution given by Disposer has  actually helped me to fix the issue. I forgot to update the answer here my bad.I will post it here now.